# How to disable Rails RoutingError stacktrace printout in Production log files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, stack-trace, production

In my proudction rails app, I got all types of random attacks requesting for asp, zip and rar files. Rails rendered 404 page as expected, but my production log file is jammed with RoutingError stacktrace dump like the following.

My question is: can I block URLs with certain patterns in Apache/Passenger? Or at least can I configure Rails to just log the error itself and not to print the entire stacktrace? Thanks!

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 100.222.237.7 at 2011-03-22 10:59:54) [GET]

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/include/upfile_flash.asp" with {:host=>"www.myhost.com", :method=>:get, :domain=>"myhost.com", :subdomain=>"www"}):
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:92:in `process_request'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in `main_loop'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:441:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:381:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:252:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:377:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:222:in `start'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:247:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:145:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:278:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
  passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'

Rendering /myapp/public/404.html (404 Not Found)
```

Answer (score 10):

Rails 4 and 5 answer:

```
match '*any', to: 'not_found#anything', via: [:get, :post]
```

To match a wildcard parameter, it must have a name assigned to it - `any` in this case.

```
class NotFoundController < ApplicationController
  def anything
    Logger.new('log/not_found.log').info(request.fullpath)
    # To render nothing:
    # head :not_found #Rails 5
    # render nothing: true, status: :not_found # for Rails 4

    #To render 404 page
    render file: 'public/404.html', status: :not_found, layout: false
  end
end
```

Comment: if you're using ActiveStorage you will need to add a constraint see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303733/unknown-format-error-for-image-png-when-getting-url-for-blob

Answer (score 9):

You could add a catch all route after all your other routes that would catch this stuff and render a controller/action of your choosing:

```
match '*' => 'errors#not_found'
```

You could even choose to only match .asp or whatever if you wanted:

```
match '*.:format' => 'errors#not_found', :constraints => {:format => /(asp|zip|rar)/i}
```