# Hide ActionController::RoutingError in logs for assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a rails app that has a WP home page, and also some images that are being load from WP. On localhost we don't have access to WP content that leads to having a lot of routing errors in logs, in example:

```
Started GET "/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/facebook-icon1.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-20 15:10:48 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/facebook-icon1.png"):
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
```

Considering we have 5 images on the page we end up having 5 routing errors for each request.
How can I hide these type of errors from logs in dev environment?

Comment: Try this: `config.assets.logger = nil`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Doesn't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Had this exact problem. Create a logger.rb file in your initializers folder and add this code:

```
# spammers were blowing up our logs
# this suppresses routing errors
if Rails.env.production?
    class ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
      alias_method :old_log_error, :log_error
      def log_error(env, wrapper)
        if wrapper.exception.is_a?  ActionController::RoutingError
          return
        else
          old_log_error env, wrapper
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Remove the condition "if Rails.env.production?" and it will suppress Routing errors in all environments.

Comment: I need this only for development, so I used `if Rails.env.development?`. Also, as you can see in gist I posted above it still generates logs, shorter than it was before I admit, but there are still some traces. Any chances to remove them at all.. to leave let's say only the requests.. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this code is easily adaptable to filter any log types out you want, or you could change it to only log certain types. If you take a moment to read through the code you can see where it decides to return without logging, or to go ahead and send info to the log. Change to suit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this [silencer](https://github.com/stve/silencer) gem can help you.

Usage:

In your environment:

```
require 'silencer/logger'

config.middleware.swap Rails::Rack::Logger, Silencer::Logger, :silence => [%r{^/wp-content/}]
```

Comment: Could you be more precise? What does it do exactly? How does the original poster need to use it? etc. Please, add an example of code.

Comment: Nope, I even tried to silence all of the GET requests for the sake of testing if this works at all.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I installed this gem, add the config to my application.rb and it works well for me.